# how to make ActiveRecord bump updated_at on new has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When adding records to a `has_many` association and saving the parent, that parent's `updated_at` is not bumped:

```
order = Order.new
order.save
pp order
  => #<Order id: 3, created_at: "2013-04-18 15:25:09", updated_at: "2013-04-18 15:25:09"> 
order.line_items << LineItem.new()
pp order.line_items
  => [#<LineItem id: 4, order_id: 3, created_at: "2013-04-18 15:26:16", updated_at: "2013-04-18 15:26:29", product_id: 123>] 
order.save
pp order.reload
  => #<Order id: 3, created_at: "2013-04-18 15:25:09", updated_at: "2013-04-18 15:25:09">
```

This makes sense, beacause `Order` it not touched; the foreign key lives on the `LineItem`.

However, in this case, I'd like to query the `Order` and find only `Order`s that have recieved  new `LineItem`s in the last 30 minutes (i.e: were "updated" in the last 30 minutes).

I am not sure what is best to do here, and how I could achieve this easily. Is there some flag or method I could set to have AR update the parents `updated_at` like described? Or should I do this via some hook? If so, what hook? Or should I store this timestamp in a different column?

Note that I could query the `line_items.updated_at` trough a `join(:line_items)`, but that would probably make my code more cluttered and less performant: or is this the preferred way for such issues in Rails?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to include `touch: true` along with `belongs_to :order` association.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
end


class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, touch: true
end
```

This will update the `updated_at` column for the associated order. More docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-touch)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the touch option, as shown below.

```
class LineItems < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, :touch => true
  ...
end
```

This will update the "update_at" of the parent Order whenever the lineitem is saved or destroyed.

Quoting from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html,

> :touch
>
> ```
> If true, the associated object will be touched (the updated_at/on attributes set to now) when this record is either saved or destroyed.
> ```
>
> If you specify a symbol, that attribute will be updated with the
>   current time in addition to the updated_at/on attribute.