# Is there an easy way to query by last update of activerecord associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm looking for a simple way to query `updated_at` through the [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) of an ActiveRecord model.  Specifically, I want to be able to query for the records **OR** related records (`belongs_to`, `has_many`) that have changed since a certain date.

I know that I could use the `:touch` [option on the associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087862/how-to-make-activerecord-bump-updated-at-on-new-has-many-association) to update, but because I have **lots** of different relations so I don't want to do so — it would escalate quickly through cascading relationships.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12946091/2238259

Try the above, it provides a way to query for date ranges, you'll probably want a date X..Date.today

Comment: Thanks — that's the query I need to look at the primary model, but it doesn't pick up the `updated_at` of the related records.  This would only work if I put the `:touch` on each relationship (which I can't do).